# How to stop an exe file process in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, process

How to stop an .exe file using java. I have a .exe which starts with a button click on jsp page. Now am not sure how to stop this using java. Below is the jave code snippet to start the .exe file. Can anybody have a solution for stopping it?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("C:\\tools\\server\\grd.exe" );
        out.println("ServerStarted");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process is unique, you could try the following. Use it with care.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("cmd /c taskkill /F /IM grd.exe");
```

See more in [*Kill a process with tskill or taskkill*](http://www.jptechnical.com/blog/2013/04/08/kill-a-process-with-tskill-or-taskkill/).

Comment: Thanks so much, this did worked. This is a very useful answer for some one looking to start and stop an .exe commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can kill the `Process`

```
Process p = ...    
p.destroy();
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) states

> Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process
>   object is forcibly terminated.

You need to keep the reference to the `Process` across requests if you're going to kill it in the future, possibly in `HttpSession` attributes.

In your servlet methods

```
Process p = ...    
req.getSession(true).setAttribute("process", p);
```

In a future request (within the same session)

```
Process p = (Process) req.getSession().getAttribute("process");
```

Comment: Could you please give a small sample if possible.

Comment: @user Sample of what?

Comment: sample code snippet for  keeping the reference to the process across requests

Comment: @user2266817 It's just playing with the session attributes. Take a look.